# Hide Image on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using fade in and fade out to blink an image.

```
  <i id="abc" class="icon-thumbs-up glowed"></i>
  <br /><i id="abc1" class="icon-thumbs-up glowed"></i>
  <br /><i id="abc2" class="icon-thumbs-up glowed"></i>

  <br /><br />
  <input type="button" value="abc" onclick="ShowImage('abc')" />
  <input type="button" value="abc1" onclick="ShowImage('abc1')" />
  <input type="button" value="abc2" onclick="ShowImage('abc2')" />
```

Its working fine but I want to hide that image when I click some button how to do that

I tried with

```
$("#" + id).hide(); //To hide
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
```

but sometime automatically its showing the image

I tried here.

http://jsbin.com/atofif/105/edit

```
loop("abc");
loop("abc1");
loop("abc2");

function loop(id){
    $('#' + id).fadeIn(700, function(){
      $(this).fadeOut(700,loop(id));
    });
}

function ShowImage(id){
   $("#" + id).hide();
}
```

Please help to hide the image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So when the button is clicked, the image should never be faded in at all?

Comment: yes nothing will happen.. means no effect will shown in UI.

Comment: Is it possible to use an animated gif instead of fade-in/out your images? Then your script will work.

Comment: I don't get why a function called `ShowImage(id)` should actually hide something

Comment: sorry my fault it should be hide image
http://jsbin.com/atofif/113/edit

Comment: @lemil77: Sorry ,No I can't use any gif image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.stop(1,1)` should do the trick!

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/atofif/120/edit)**</kbd>

```
function loop(id){
    $('#'+ id).fadeIn(700, function(){
          $(this).fadeOut( 700, loop(id) );
    });
}


function HideImage(id){
   $("#" + id).stop(1,1).hide();
}


loop("abc");
loop("abc1");
loop("abc2");
```

Comment: @roXon that link provided by you is working some time and sometime its showing the image.can you please recheck your answer

Comment: @user1926138 sorry, my fault I pasted the wrong code. Edited. It's `stop(1,1)`

Comment: @roXon still the image is showing. Please recheck when i click abc its working. when i click abc1 its showing hiding the image for some time and again it start blinking.
can you please recheck your solution

Comment: Its full filled my requirement